# xml schemas choosing a child element based on parent attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

i have a parent element (product) with an attribute (category) that can take any of 2 values (perishable, and nonPerishable). If the item is perishable, i want to have the child-element "food", and if it is not perishable, i want to have the child-element "stock". From looking, i gather that this can be done in XSD 1.1, but not XSD 1.0. However, i am not finding how to do this.

Below is my code, shortened to show the important parts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="products">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="product" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:choice>
               <xs:element name="food">
                 <xs:complexType>
                   /*DEFINED FOOD HERE*?
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="stock">
                 <xs:complexType>
                   /*DEFINED STOCK HERE*/
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
             </xs:choice>
           </xs:sequence>
           <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
           <xs:attribute name="category">
             <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                 <xs:enumeration value="perishable"/>
                 <xs:enumeration value="nonPerishable"/>
               </xs:restriction>
             </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:attribute>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like:

```
 <perishable>
     <food>cheese</food>
    </perishable>


<xs:element name="perishable">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="food" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: sorry echew, this dosent help. Re-read the first paragraph please :)

Comment: Give me an example of how you want the xml to look like.
Do you want an element to defined no perishable if it doesn't meet the perishable criteria?

Comment: product has an attribute that can have either perishable or nonPerishable as its value. If the attribute has the value perishable, i want a food element in the product element. If the attribute has the value nonPerishable, i want a stock element inside the product element